# git bundle creating duplicate refs

Tags: git, bundle

I am trying to use git bundle to create a backup of my local repository. I am running the following to create the bundle on the source machine.

```
git bundle create myback.bundle mybranch --all
```

I am using the all parameter because I want to backup all branches on the source machine.

When I go to verify this bundle on the backup machine, I am seeing duplicate refs which seem to be preventing me from cloning from the bundle. See "mybranch" below is duplicated.

> 5e6e24e00edb98e5c12af39ef9ed895106600d69 refs/heads/mybranch
>   5e6e24e00edb98e5c12af39ef9ed895106600d69 refs/heads/mybranch
>   d97386c728189eed6acbd39ca4385e1c75c5ff22 refs/heads/otherbranch
>   6d81c25f0fc2e59303d66340d5b56141de20a6cf refs/heads/br3
>   e7fdaff9c298784dc19f3f42922541f2b8eb81f0 refs/heads/master
>   7deee21ec20e7e57183e362a49895022df4acdab refs/heads/br4
>   ec11a354241c61a71ca922f41118e3e83f911e28 refs/remotes/origin/br1
>   970e3949edbe7a7846e3d80e9633b3f1a4e40bc6 refs/remotes/origin/mybranch
>   e7fdaff9c298784dc19f3f42922541f2b8eb81f0 refs/remotes/origin/br4

On the source machine, I am not seeing this duplication of refs when running

> git show-ref

Any idea how this duplicated ref is getting into the bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--all` argument grabs all branches including `mybranch`, so by also specifying the branch you're asking git bundle to include it twice. I have tried removing `mybranch` from your command line and got all the branches, including mybranch, without duplication.

In my own tests (Git 2.4.0 on Linux), the duplicated ref only causes a warning to be issued when I clone the bundle. I wonder why it's causing an actual failure for you. In any case, I expect using just `--all` will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you that seems to be the problem. I will verify from the remote/backup machine, and then mark as answer.